# JAVA +  create HashMap in place of function

Tags: java

I write the following two functions
I want to implement the functions with HashMap ( in place of functions )
how to do that?

```
static void someFunction(int count, int[] anArray)  
{      
  for ( int i=0;i<anArray[count];i = i + 1) 
  {
    System.out.print("#");
  }
  System.out.println("");
} 

static void someFunctionB(int[] anArray , int count,  String stringfinal, String sttr)  
{      
  anArray[count]= stringfinal.replaceAll("[^"+sttr+"]", "").length();
}   

someFunctionB(anArray ,  count,   stringfinal,  sttr  );        

someFunction(count, anArray);
```

Comment: why I get Vote -1 , ? I only start learn Java before 3 days , -:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using any functions (apart from `public static void main(String[] args)`), you could do something like:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> mapThatPretendsToBeAnArray = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer>();
mapThatPretendsToBeAnArray.put(0, 17);
mapThatPretendsToBeAnArray.put(1, 5);
mapThatPretendsToBeAnArray.put(2, 1);
mapThatPretendsToBeAnArray.put(3, 319);

//someFunction()
for (int i = 0; i < mapThatPretendsToBeAnArray.get(1); i++) {
    System.out.print("#");
}
System.out.println("");

//someFunctionB()
mapThatPretendsToBeAnArray.put(3, "stringFinal".replaceAll("[^"+"sttr"+"]", "").length());
```

But of course, `someFunction()` and `someFunctionB()` are more useful, because they let you parameterize your arguments instead of having to pick hard-coded ones as in this example.

Comment: why mapThatPretendsToBeAnArray.get(1); (get 1?)

Comment: @david - It's arbitrary, for the sake of example.  The `1` is doing the same thing that your `count` parameter does inside of `someFunction()`, it's just an index/key into the array/map.  Also, why not use a `List` instead of a `Map`?

Comment: mapThatPretendsToBeAnArray.put(0, 17); mean stringFinal=0 and sttr=17 ?

Comment: @david - It is equivalent to saying `anArray[0] = 17;`, or `anArray[0] = "seventeen letters".length();`.

Comment: Last question why 3 before , "stringFinal"?

Comment: @david - The `3` is the destination index, it is like saying `anArray[3]= stringfinal.replaceAll("[^"+sttr+"]", "").length();`.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that a Map is a Key-Value data structure - you could potentially use a String, or some other more meaningful identifier for your keys, for example.  Also, although the behavior is superficially the same in this instance, you're actually doing something very different underneath.

Using your API:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class CounterHelper {

  static int key = 6;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    someFunctionB(hashMap, key, "[^toRemove] remaining", "toRemove");
    someFunction(key, hashMap);
  }

  public static void someFunction(int key, Map<Integer, Integer> hashMap) {      
    for (int i=0; i < hashMap.get(key); i++) {
      System.out.print("#");
    }
    System.out.println("");
  } 

  public static void someFunctionB(Map<Integer, Integer> hashMap, int key, String stringfinal, String sttr) {
    hashMap.put(key, stringfinal.replaceAll("[^"+sttr+"]", "").length());
  }   

}
```

Just using a Map:

```
public class CounterHelper {

  static int value = 4;
  static int key = 6;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      java.util.Map<Integer, Integer> hashMap = new java.util.HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
      hashMap.put(key, value);

      int hashes = hashMap.get(key);
      for (int i = 0; i < hashes; i++) {
          System.out.println("#");
      }
  }

  }
```